# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `logins` (`network` varchar(64),`email` varchar(64),`password` varchar(64));
```

Gives me the error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `logins` (`network`
>   varchar(64),`email` varchar(64), `password` var' at line 1"

How can I fix this? Removing ` does nothing.

Comment: MySQL error messages usually *start* where things go wrong; which means it seems to not even like that you are using `CREATE`. How are you running this? If it is in a script, what precedes this?

Comment: MySQL error message contain after *"near"* the fragment of the query where the error was detected. Yours contain the entire query. Most probably you issued two queries and forgot the separator between them (`;`).

Comment: Maybe network or password are reserved words.

Comment: @KoltPenny the purpose of quoting the names using backticks ("\`") is to allow the usage of reserved words as object names (databases, tables, columns, indexes etc). `password` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-P) in MySQL, `network` is not.

Comment: My guess: You've copied the query from something like MS Word and the string contains a (not visible) control character.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon. I’ve had drivers not handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The problem was copy/paste as suggested above, but not due to control characters.  The font used in the source showed back-ticks and forward-ticks in place of single quotes.  Replacing those with basic single quote characters solved it for me.